# dicom image : area calculation

Tags: matlab, coordinates, area, dicom

I am developing a program in matlab to to view diacom files and measure the area of a particular target region in the image. Target area will be given as a manual input (number of points).

I know little about the dicom analyzing. But I feel that simply inputting the points (coordinates) to the matlab function polyarea(X,Y) will not give the actual area.
I need to know actual area in mm^2.
I know pixel spacing and slice thickness too.

Please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coordinates you supply to `polyarea` are measured in pixels, then the result will be measured in square pixels.

If you know the width of a pixel (in mm), then your area (in mm<sup>2</sup>) is pixelarea * pixelwidth<sup>2</sup>, i.e.:

```
area = polyarea(X,Y) * power(pixelwidth,2)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Simon...But the pixelwidth in x direction and y direction are different..Is it correct to do like this.. area = polyarea(X,Y) * pixelarea(pixel width * pixel height)                                                          Or is this require any mapping from the image coordinate system to real world coordinate system

Comment: Yes, it's correct to do `area = polyarea(X,Y) * pixelwidth * pixelheight`. There's no need to map coordinates, as distance and area are location invariant.